# I'm trying to learn how to properly separate class header and code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-7-x64

I have a class project that I did from college that "works", but isn't constructed properly.

It has a Date class and a Person class.

In my "working" code, all of the class data (constructors, members, and functions) are contained within a single header file for each class (a separate file for each class).

The program loads text file data (Persons, presidents and actors) into a vector, sorts, filters and prints the data on the console, and saves it to a file.

In the Person class constructor (and functions), the Date class is instantiated for a "birthdate" object. Then the birthday is used in the program.

The problem I'm having is this:

I can easily instantiate "Date" in the Person constructor and members, if all the class code is in a header file for each class, AND I make the Date the "Parent" class for Person. But if I don't do both of these things, then "Person" doesn't know anything about "Date" and cannot instantiate anything from Date.

If I use an #include "Date.h" in Person.h, this creates even more problems and doesn't work either.

Of course, "Date" is not a proper parent class for "Person", but it was the only way I could hack the code to make it work lol. When I first coded this years ago in college, I never did figure out how to divide the class code properly in so that it would compile and run. The "working code" with all the class code in a header file is my hack. I want to learn how to do it the right way.

I have pasted in the bare minimum example below of what "works" and what doesn't. Any tips to make this code work with the classes divided into header and .cpp files would be much appreciated.

#### What works:

```
class Date {
    private:
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;

    public:
        Date::Date() {}
        virtual ~Date() {}
        Date( int aMonth, int aDay, int aYear ) {
            this->month = aMonth;
            this->year = aYear;
            this->day = aDay;
        }

        // "Getter" functions for the Date class
        int getMonth(){return this->month;}
        int getYear() {return this->year;}
        int getDay() {return this->day;}

        // "Setter" functions for the Date class
        void setDay( int aDay ){ this->day = aDay; }
        void setMonth( int aMonth )  { this->month = aMonth; }
        void setYear( int aYear ) { this->year = aYear; }
};

class Person : public Date{
    private:
        string title;
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        Date birthDate;

    public:
        Person::Person() {}
        Person(string title, string firstName, string lastName, Date birthDay);
        virtual ~Person() {}

        //"Getter" functions for the Person class
        string getTitle() { return title; }
        string getFirstName() { return firstName; }
        string getLastName() { return lastName; }
        Date getBirthDay() { return birthDate; }

        //"Setter" functions for the Person class
        void setTitle(string Title) { this->title = Title; }
        void setFirstName(string fName) { this->firstName = fName; }
        void setLastName (string lName) { this->lastName = lName; }
        void setBirthday (Date aBirthday) { this->birthDate = aBirthday; }
};
```

#### What doesn't work (Doesn't compile):

**Date.h**

```
class Date {
    private:
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;
    public:
        Date();
        virtual ~Date() {}
        Date( int aMonth, int aDay, int aYear );

        //Getters and setters
        int getMonth();
        int getYear() ;
        int getDay();
        void setDay( int aDay );
        void setMonth( int aMonth ) ;
        void setYear( int aYear ) ;

};
```

**Date.cpp**

```
#include "Date.h"
Date::Date() {}
Date::Date( int aMonth, int aDay, int aYear ) {
    this->month = aMonth;
    this->year = aYear;
    this->day = aDay;
}

int Date::getMonth(){return this->month;}
int Date::getYear() {return this->year;}
int Date::getDay()  {return this->day;}

//"Setter" functions for the Date class
void Date::setDay( int aDay ){ this->day = aDay; }
void Date::setMonth( int aMonth )  { this->month = aMonth; }
void Date::setYear( int aYear ) { this->year = aYear; }
```

**Person.h**

```
#include <string>

class Person{
    private:
        string title;
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        Date birthDate;

    public:
        //Person::Person() {}
        Person(string title, string firstName, string lastName, Date birthDay); 

        //"Getter" functions for the Person class
        string getTitle() { return title; }
        string getFirstName() { return firstName; }
        string getLastName() { return lastName; }
        Date getBirthDay() { return birthDate; }

        //"Setter" functions for the Person class
        void setTitle(string Title) { this->title = Title; }
        void setFirstName(string fName) { this->firstName = fName; }
        void setLastName (string lName) { this->lastName = lName; }
        void setBirthday (Date aBirthday) { this->birthDate = aBirthday; }
    };
```

**Person.cpp**

```
#include "Person.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Person class constructor with 0 arguments
Person::Person(string atitle, string afirstName, string alastName, Date abirthDay) {
    title = atitle,
          firstName = afirstName,
          lastName = alastName,
          birthday = abirthDay)
}

//"Getter" functions for the Person class
string Person::getTitle() { return title; }
string Person::getFirstName() { return firstName; }
string Person::getLastName() { return lastName; }
Date Person::getBirthDay() { return birthDate; }

//"Setter" functions for the Person class
void Person::setTitle(string Title) { this->title = Title; }
void Person::setFirstName(string fName) { this->firstName = fName; }
void Person::setLastName (string lName) { this->lastName = lName; }
void Person::setBirthday (Date aBirthday) { this->birthDate = aBirthday; }
```

#### Operating system notes

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 on a Windows 7 PC.

Comment: I just noticed that the code for Person.h in the problem code has body code for the getters/setters. I just took that out and it still won't compile.

Comment: Always use header guards. With that said, what error are you getting with the second snippet? I don't see where you're include Date.h for Person.h.

Comment: `class Person : public Date{` Why would Person need to inherit from Date?

Comment: Person.h needs to #include Date.h to be able to use Date as the return type for getBirthDay. What is the first error of the (as you describe it) "creates even more problems"?

Comment: I tried using #include "Date.h" and it just produces different errors like this: 1>c:\users\jhs publishing pc\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\practice\practice\date.h(3): error C2011: 'Date' : 'class' type redefinition
1>          c:\users\jhs publishing pc\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\practice\practice\date.h(3) : see declaration of 'Date'
1>c:\users\jhs publishing pc\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\practice\practice\person.h(13): error C2079: 'Person::birthDate' uses undefined class 'Date'

Comment: A `Person` is usually not a `Date`, so it doesn't qualify for the inheritance relationship.  A person *has-a* birthdate, which indicates a containment relationship.

Comment: I explained above that it was a hack to make Date visible to Person. It "works", but it's lousy code.

Comment: What's the error if you remove the inheritance?

Comment: @drescherjm - It shouldn't... that's roughly what the original question is.

Comment: If you're getting redefined issues, it sounds like it's header guards. You're using VS, so add the line `#pragma once` to the top of each class file and try again.

Comment: But after I split the code into header and .cpp files, even making Date the Parent class of Person doesn't work. So something else is needed

Comment: I added #pragma once to the top of each file. Now get error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'title' as the first error and lots more

Comment: Adding the pragma line did resolve the inability of VS to recognize the Date class, but still getting a lot of misc strange errors error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Comment: @Max "doesn't work" is about as nebulous as you can get. The exact error message produced would be considerably more informative, and belongs in your question. Setup header guards or a pragma-once as suggested. And btw, ***all*** your standard strings `string` should be `std::string`. *don't* "fix" that by shoving a `using namespace std;` in a header file.

Comment: error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'getTitle'

Comment: @WhozCraig, that's interesting that you should mention that. I tried using only std:: instead of both, but VS doesn't seem to work unless both are present in some way. Either VS is buggy or I just don't understand how to use it

Comment: Sorry, what I meant by "doesn't work" is that the program will not compile. If I can get it to compile, I can get the rest myself.

Comment: @Max Something [like this](http://pastebin.com/v5U78V9v), though that may be a little off the radar.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks a lot. It does compile, however the code still isn't split into header and cpp files. I'll come back when I see the results of that. This does work, though, with the include for Date.h, so there is progress!

Comment: @Max the little code posted didn't really need to be split into cpp files, but if you're just wanting to learn how to do it that is a decent starting point. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent redefinition errors, add include guards to header files. To be portable, use:

```
#if !defined(THE_HEADER_NAME_H)
#define THE_HEADER_NAME_H
// Usual code and declarations here.
#endif
```

In Visual Studio, you can use:

```
#pragma once
// Usual code and declarations here.
```

In headers, don't write (at global scope level)

```
using namespace XXXXX
```

because that will cause all files including yours to also use namespace XXXXX which they may not want imposed upon them. If you use types that are in a namespace, type out the entire type name with namespace, so use:

```
std::string getTitle()
```

(In a cpp file, you can have 'using namespace XXXXX' after any #includes)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems IMHO.

First is the guards problem that Scott Langham's answer will solve.

The second is a problem of namespaces.

I assume that in your working source, you have (directly on indirectly via stdafx.h or another include) :

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;
```

It is not recommended to have `using namespace std;` in a `.h` header file ... but that means that you should use `std::string` instead of `string`:

date.h

```
class Date {
    private:
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;
    public:
        Date::Date() { }                                                //Date class constructor with 0 arguments
        virtual ~Date() {}                                              //Date class destructor
        Date( int aMonth, int aDay, int aYear ) {                       //Date class constructor with 3 arguments
            this->month = aMonth;                                       // Set the private member data with the argument data
            this->year = aYear;
            this->day = aDay;
            }       
        //"Getter" functions for the Date class
        int getMonth(){return this->month;}                             
        int getYear() {return this->year;}
        int getDay() {return this->day;} 

        //"Setter" functions for the Date class
        void setDay( int aDay ){ this->day = aDay; }                    
        void setMonth( int aMonth )  { this->month = aMonth; }  
        void setYear( int aYear ) { this->year = aYear; }

};
```

person.h (string -> std::string and remove method implementations)

```
#include <string>
#include "Date.h"

class Person : public Date{

private:                                                                //Private data members
    std::string title;
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    Date birthDate;

public:
    Person::Person() {}                                                 //Person class constructor with 0 arguments
    Person(std::string title, 
        std::string firstName, 
        std::string lastName, 
        Date birthDay);                                                 //Person class constructor with 4 arguments

    virtual ~Person(){}                                                 //Person class destructor

    //"Getter" functions for the Person class
    std::string getTitle();
    std::string getFirstName();
    std::string getLastName();
    Date getBirthDay();

    //"Setter" functions for the Person class
    void setTitle(std::string Title);
    void setFirstName(std::string fName);
    void setLastName (std::string lName);
    void setBirthday (Date aBirthday);
};
```

person.cpp (fixed includes and constructor)

```
#include <string>
#include "Person.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Person class constructor with 0 arguments
Person::Person(string atitle, string afirstName, string alastName, Date abirthDay) {
    title = atitle,
          firstName = afirstName,
          lastName = alastName,
          birthDate = abirthDay;
}

//"Getter" functions for the Person class
string Person::getTitle() { return title; }
string Person::getFirstName() { return firstName; }
string Person::getLastName() { return lastName; }
Date Person::getBirthDay() { return birthDate; }

//"Setter" functions for the Person class
void Person::setTitle(string Title) { this->title = Title; }
void Person::setFirstName(string fName) { this->firstName = fName; }
void Person::setLastName (string lName) { this->lastName = lName; }
void Person::setBirthday (Date aBirthday) { this->birthDate = aBirthday; }
```

It can even be used without guards, but guard are anyway a good practice.

In fact as `Date.h` is included in `Person.h` it should really have a guard - not shown here for simplicity

Comment: Do *not* make header *inclusion* dependent on *prior* header inclusion. The `Person.h` header file should include `Date.h`  If that takes properly setting up include guards or pragmas so be it. `Person.h` needs `<string>` for `std::string`, so you include it in the header. It needs `Date.h` for `Date`, *so include it in the header*. If the `Person.cpp` file needs something else (`foo.h`) and the header does *not*, then *that* belongs in the cpp-files include list; not the headers.

Comment: Thank you WhozCraig!! I separated the class into header and cpp files, and it compiles. I will have to study this some more to understand it better. I have work experience in C, but only college with C++ (I have a BS in CS), so I'm trying to master it. Thanks again.

Comment: I have a followup question @WhozCraig, if you don't mind. What is the purpose of using const as in  const std::string Person::getFirstName() const { return firstName; } I've never seen const used like this. I know it obviously means "constant", but I've vague on its use here.

Comment: @Max it is a contract with the object that warrants non-mutable access. Ex: given a `const Person&`, your prior code would *not* allow execution of any of your 'getters" because the reference is `const` but the member fns were *not*. *Usually* "getters" are `const`, as they don't modify the object anyway, and setters are *not*.

Comment: Thank you very much. C++ is a huge pain to code. Java is a lot easier

Comment: @Max both languages have their pros and cons :)